# run sequencital background commands while keeping session

Tags: command-line, python

I have a python script that I want to run a couple of times, I am having trouble setting it to go to the command after it because the python script will eventually give an error

```
nohup python3 em.py &&killall chrome && sleep 60 &&nohup python3 em.py&
```

this is exactly what I want, but because first python script throws an error the rest don't begin.

I tried to solve by:

```
nohup python3 em.py ;killall chrome;sleep 60;nohup python3 em.py&
nohup python3 em.py ;killall chrome;sleep 60;nohup python3 em.py;
```

those fail when I leave the session of SSH (or CTRL+C), I run Ubuntu 20 how can I solve?

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to know what `em.py` is doing and how if fails since it may affect the pipeline.

I see two issues here.

First, the `nohup` shell command works on the current statement, not the whole line.  So while you have nohup on the `em.py` calls, you do not with the other two.  Try doing running a single bash with nohup on that.  And I suggest using `setsid` as it's more reliable.

Second is that the controlling terminal may not be reset properly when you log out.  You should redirect stdin/out/err properly.
I see two issues here.

```
setsid $SHELL -c 'python3 em.py; killall chrome; sleep 60; python3 em.py' </dev/null >/tmp/em.out 2>&1 &
```

You could also run the commands inside a terminal multiplexer like `screen(1)` or `tmux(1)` to avoid all this.